# accessing data inside request body while creating a customized permission

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I want to authenticate users based on some date inside request.data
I inherit from BasePermission and impelement has_permission method. It force me to call is_valid() of serializer before using the data. So, if the request is not valid or has not permission it return false. how could I discriminate between these two things

```
class HasStoreAccess(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        request_serializer = ProductInventorySerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if request_serializer.is_valid():
            for item in request_serializer.data:
                if item['store_id'] != request.user.wim_user.store_id:
                    return False
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap the request validation in a `try: except` block.

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class HasStoreAccess(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            request_serializer = ProductInventorySerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
            request_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except serializers.ValidationError:
            return False  # request is not valid
        else:
            for item in request_serializer.data:
                if item['store_id'] != request.user.wim_user.store_id:
                    return False  # no permission
            return True
```